# Multiple linear regression LSE when one of parameter is known

Tags: regression, machine-learning, least-squares, offset

Question is the following:

> For analyzing the observed data, the following regression model 
>   \begin{eqnarray}
> y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_2x_{i2}+\beta_3x_{i3}+\epsilon_i
> \end{eqnarray}
>   is chosen by a researcher. When it is known that $\beta_2=4$, how can a researcher obtain the least squares estimates for all the other unknown parameters?

Well, in my viewpoint, since the parameter $\beta_2$ is known, thus we only need to get the other unknown parameter, that is, obtain the least squares estimator focus on  $\beta_0,\beta_1,\beta_3$ only but not $\beta_2$, thus the LSE well be the same as usual, that is,
\begin{eqnarray}
\hat{\beta}_{LSE}=\hat{\beta_{0,1,3}}=(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y
\end{eqnarray}
Is this right?

Comment: Hi: That's correct but note that the $X$ matrix and the $y$ vector change because the known piece has to be subtracted from both sides of the equation. Maybe this was obvious in which case, my apologies.

Comment: Subtract $\beta_2 x_{i2}$ from $y_i$ and regress this on the remaining covariates. The least squares estimator will be $(\tilde X’\tilde X)^{-1} \tilde X’ \tilde y$ where $\tilde X$ is the covariate matrix without $x_{i2}$ and $\tilde y$ is the outcome vector with $\beta_2 x_{i2}$ subtracted.

Comment: Appreciate, I actually forget to alter the matrix representation, this is my fault.

Comment: This question is also answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/434554/919 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136602/919.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that under the constraint that $\beta_2 = 4$, you do not need to estimate $\beta_2$. But you do need to apply the constraint.

- **Step 1:** subtract $\beta_2 x_{i2}$ from $y_i$. Denote the transformed outcome by $\tilde y \equiv y_i - 4 x_{i2}$.
- **Step 2:** remove the column correspond to $x_{i2}$ from the covariate matrix $X$. Denote the resulting covariate matrix by $\tilde X$.
- **Step 3:** calculate the constrained least squares estimates as $\hat\beta_{\rm LSE} = (\tilde X' \tilde X)^{-1} \tilde X' \tilde y$.

Comment: It is equivalent, and more practical, to use an *offset* term in the model formula (in R, should exist also in other systems.) `y ~ x1 + offset(I(4*x2)) + x3, data=your_data_frame, ...)`